# How to get auctionRunType value in __getAuctions function?

Tags: flutter

```
class AllAuctions extends StatefulWidget {
final String searchString;
final String title;
final String auctionRunType;//A=All,U=Upcoming,C=Current L=Live
const AllAuctions({Key? key, required this.searchString, required this.title, required this.auctionRunType}) : super(key: key);
@override
_AllAuctions createState() => _AllAuctions();
}

class _AllAuctions extends State<AllAuctions> {
List<AuctionListModel> _auctions = [];
bool _isloggedin = true;
int _offset=0;



@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

_getAuctions();
}

@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
}
_getAuctions() async {
print(API_URL + 'auction/auction_list/' + _offset.toString()+'/' + auctionRunType);
//print the value of auctionRunType here

}

}
```

> How to get auctionRunType value in __getAuctions function I have
> passed 3 parameter from another page , I want to get auctionRunType
> the value in _getAuctions function so that depending on it I can call
> API

Answer (score 0):

`auctionRunType` is inside the widget `AllAuctions`. your function is in `_AllAuctions` which is its state. You can reach fields from the widget by simply putting `widget.` in front of it, so you can try to see if `widget.auctionRunType` works here.